# ASUS EPC 1015CX won't boot with display after installing additional drivers

Tags: 12.04, graphics, display, asus

I have a ASUS EPC 1015CX with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed using wubi alongside Windows 7. It worked perfectly after installing except that the supported screen resolution was only 800*600 instead of 1024*600. The specifications of the 1015CX device can be found [here](http://in.asus.com/Eee/Eee_PC/Eee_PC_1015CX/#specifications)

I tried installing additional drivers which was Broadcom for wireless and Cedarview-drm. By this time there was no display coming up after the boot. I could hear a voice and then the letters I typed got pronounced correctly. So, I guessed the issue has to be with the graphic terminal. I tried repair broken packages in the menu and booted and the display is now at 1024*600. But, if I restart normally the problem continues like before.

As per what I found out after searching, I again opened additional drivers and installed Cedarview-graphics-driver. I tried restarting hoping it will work. But again, the result was same. There was no display but the system was working.

I did more searching and followed the instructions found [here.](http://daily.siebler.eu/2012/06/ubuntu-12-04-driver-for-intel-cedarview-atom-n2000-und-d2000-serie/) But still the result was same. I am keen to switch to linux from windows after hearing and learning great things about it. I know this community is good and always helping. I wanted to thank you all for the help in advance.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong and help me to switch to linux from this same old windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling proprietary drives through typing "Drivers..." in the Dash and selecting the Additional Drivers there. There will be one Broadcom and one Cedar Trail driver; the latter is what you need - apparently, the new Cedar Trail Intel Atom series didn't have the proper graphics support at 12.04 launch, so now there's a driver that's available that fixes the issue.

Sorry for the late reply, but I only ran into this issue today installing 12.04 on a brand new 1015CX. Hope this helps - it worked for me :)

Comment: I have installed this already. But my problem is after installing I am getting a blank screen while booting up.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same netbook 1015cx. i didnt have any problem . try installing with updates. in my setup the opensource gma500_gfx driver gives a good resolution 1024*600. i tried installing cedartraildrivers but my system hangs and I had to reboot and finally give up the idea of installing those drivers.